# SP - CSOM Load specific properties of object

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, csom

How to get specific properties of object with C# Client SharePoint object model?

My code with JSOM is:

**Collection of objects:**

```
clientContext.load(items, "Include(ID, Title, EmpDays, EmpPosition, EmpDirection, EmpDepartment)");
```

**One object:**

```
clientContext.load(user, "Title", "LoginName");
```

How to do this with C# **C**lient **S**harePoint **O**bject **M**odel ?

Thank you previously!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a lambda expression like below,

For one item

```
clientContext.Load(user, u => u.Title, u => u.LoginName);
```

For a collection

```
ctx.Load(items, i => i.Include(f => f.Id, f => f.Title));
```

See here https://www.itunity.com/article/loading-specific-values-lambda-expressions-sharepoint-csom-api-windows-powershell-1249